# Origin of a kworker-thread

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

On my newly installed system using kernel 3.2 I see a kworker-thread which is constantly consuming CPU. I'd like to find out which part of kernel/module has created this workqueue.

How to track a kworker-thread named for example ''kworker/0:3 to its origin in kernel-space?

I tried to look into /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/workqueue, but wasn't able to figure it out.

Comment: You might want to ask this on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: The kworker process handles ACPI wakeup calls from the BIOS. Older kernels ( < 2.6.35 IIRC ) don't seem to have them (at least not my laptop with 2.6.32 ).

Comment: @Shahbaz maybe, but my question has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: Then maybe [superuser](http://superuser.com/?as=1). Anyway, stack overflow is for programming questions. This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

(Seems to me this is rather off topic here, but here's the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22851/why-is-kworker-consuming-so-many-resources-on-linux-3-0-0-12-server/65270#65270) I posted on [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22851/why-is-kworker-consuming-so-many-resources-on-linux-3-0-0-12-server/65270#65270).)

I found [this thread on lkml](https://lkml.org/lkml/2011/3/31/68) that answers your question a little. (It seems even Linus himself was puzzled as to how to find out the origin of those threads.)

Basically, there are two ways of doing this:

```
$ echo workqueue:workqueue_queue_work > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/set_event
$ cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe > out.txt
(wait a few secs)
```

For this you will need [ftrace](http://www.elinux.org/Ftrace) to be compiled in your kernel.

This will output what threads are all doing, and is useful for tracing multiple small jobs.

```
cat /proc/THE_OFFENDING_KWORKER/stack
```

This will output the stack of a single thread doing a lot of work. It may allow you to find out what caused this specific thread to hog the CPU (for example). `THE_OFFENDING_KWORKER` is the pid of the kworker in the process list.

Answer (score 9):

So, after some time I found the solution. In fact Anthon is right, it is the ACPI-subsystem which sends interrupts. On *my* system I disabled the following interrupts and the kworker-thread is calmed down.

```
echo disable > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe1B
echo disable > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe08
```

However until now haven't identified what the bogus IRQs coming from `gpe08` and `gpe1B`.

Comment: how did you arrive at those particular interrupts?

Comment: IIRC, brute force. Somewhere I found that the source of those kworkers are in the acpi-subsystem and then I disabled one gpe after another and found out that these two are having an effect.

Comment: you can run      grep . -r /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/     to get a list of interrupts with the number of times each one was triggered. The ones with big values are probably the problematic ones.

Answer (score 3):

kworker / watchdog causing high load regularly when not on cable power - workaround

Had kworker (cause kernel_thread_helper+0x6/0x10 ?) thread 1 spiking to 100% of a cpu for 1 second every 5 seconds only if laptop powered by cable. No problems on battery power. Did not matter if battery fully charged.

It more or less came out of the blue, so I guess the recent Ubuntu update was the cause (3.2.0-55-generic-pae now).

Was looking for half a day, trying to figure out wft the root cause is and endet up trying to disable all acpi interrupts, which did not matter.

Adding GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”acpi=off” to /etc/defaults/grub helped in the end.

As I discovered right now I added it with these exact special unicode quotes, which might explain the incompatibility with "quiet splash" (with default quotes) which puzzled me. I have to look into some more grub issues (boot menu not being displayed however I try, default entry config not used ...) so I will leave that testing for later.

PS: a week later, the problem is back (without restart, only suspend in between). There might be a correlation to using an usb mouse. Power down/power up helped (restart did not). Threw all grub options away. I am expecting the problem to show up again sometime.

PPS: Took some time (half a year), but it is back again after a resume from ram. No recent updates, just plugging/unplugging power, as I often do. No USB devices plugged/unplugged. Had a totem running (but nothing playing) during suspend. Power down/power up with power cable plugged did *not* help, power down/power up with power cable unplugged did.

Answer (score 3):

An additional solution (that I've already posted in different [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61697317/12150026) not a while ago and maybe you can find there additional solutions to your problem) for these kinds of problems is to use the **perf tool** (It's not always enabled by default and you may need to [install perf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50145/how-to-install-perf-monitoring-tool) on your device).

**Step 1:** Set perf to record workqueue events:

```
perf record -e 'workqueue:*' -ag -T
```

**Step 2:** Run it as long as you think you need to catch the event (10 seconds should be ok if this event is frequent enough, but you can let it run longer, depending on the available free space you have left on your device) and then stop it with `Ctrl + C`.

**Step 3:** Print the captured events (on Linux versions < 4.1 I think it should be -f and not -F):

```
perf script -F comm,pid,tid,time,event,trace
```

This will display something like this:

```
      task-name    pid/tid     timestamp    event 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    turtle        9201/9201   1473.339166:  workqueue:workqueue_queue_work:    work struct=0xef20d4c4 function=pm_runtime_work workqueue=0xef1cb600 req_cpu=8 cpu=1
    turtle        9201/9201   1473.339176:  workqueue:workqueue_activate_work: work struct 0xef20d4c4
    kworker/0:3  24223/24223  1473.339221:  workqueue:workqueue_execute_start: work struct 0xef20d4c4: function pm_runtime_work
    kworker/0:3  24223/24223  1473.339248:  workqueue:workqueue_execute_end:   work struct 0xef20d4c4
```

**Step 4:** Analyzing the table above:

In the first row, a task named `turtle (pid 9201)` is pushing the work `pm_runtime_work` to the workqueue. 
In the third row, we can see that the `kworker/0:3 (pid 24223)` is executing that work.

**Summary:** Now back to your questions, we see that `kworker/0:3` has been requested by `turtle` task to run the `pm_runtime_work` function.
So let's go back to the code and see what this `pm_runtime_work` function does! Maybe here we'll manage to understand why it consumes so much CPU.

Answer (score -3):

kworker is a kernel thread which processes workqueues.This thread is created in the file linux/kernel/workqueue.c file.

Comment: It's obvious from the question that he already knows kworker is related to workqueues, and wants to know which part of the kernel is responsible for his CPU consumption. Pointing to workqueue.c is unhelpful.