# how many ways we can create a process in linux using c

Tags: c, linux, shell

I have confusion in creating a process in Linux. Up to now I thought that we can create the process by calling the following system calls.

1. `system()`
2. `exec()` family of system call
3. `fork()` system call

but:

1. **system():** But as "system" system call executing the input executable on shell and shell is creating a child process for the execution of input .here shell is calling child process then we can say that fork is creating process for this.
2. **exec family of system call:** As this family of system call over write the current running process with new process.So it is also creating a new process but using same address space. As I think it is also calling call fork for creating the process.

I am confused with the fact all the above is possible way of creating a new process or only fork system.

Comment: [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) is not a system call.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**`exec` family of system call does not call `fork`, neither it creates a new process.**
It only overwrites the existing process with the new binary.

**In `linux` user programs, `fork` is the only function to create new process.** Though `fork` internally calls `clone` and other system calls.

In other hands, `system` is only a wrapper to `fork` and `exec`. The actual task of creating a process is done by `fork` in `system`. **So `system` is not a way to create new process.**

Answer (score 3):

`fork()` creates a copy of your process. This is where you actually *create a process* in a POSIX environment like Linux. To precisely answer your question title, `fork()` is the only way to create a process.

What `exec()` does for you is then to replace a process (for example the process you just created with `fork()`) by another process, so `exec()` doesn't itself create a process but is often accompanied with `fork()`, since you usually want to create another process that is different from your current one.

Underneath the `system()` call, there's just a `fork()` followed by an `exec()`, so it's not a new way of creating a process.

Answer (score 3):

In POSIX environment, You can create a process though `fork` system call without any exception. Fork will create a process.

`exec` family of function just load binary of other program to the address space of current process(which call the exec() system call).

In `system()` it is internally use `fork()` followed  by `exec()`system call.

Answer (score 2):

There is only two ways to create a new process: the system calls `fork` and `clone`.

The other functions mentioned, fall into two categories:

1. `exec()` family: These replace the contents of a process with some other program. Usually `exec()` is used right after a call to `fork` or `clone` to turn one of the resulting processes into a process of the desired application. When a `bash` executes a `gcc` command, for instance, it first forks itself, then it makes one of the two resulting `bash` processes into a `gcc` process using the `exec()` family.
2. `system()` family: These encapsulate a `fork`/`clone` system call and a corresponding `exec()` call, possibly doing fancy stuff like connecting `stdin` and `stdout`, etc.

Note that all of these functions `fork()`, `clone()`, `exec()`, `system()`, etc. are system call wrappers defined by the standard C library (which is always present), not the system calls themselves. As such, counterintuitively, `fork()` is a wrapper for the `clone` system call on current systems. Not that it matters much. However, the C library functions are standardized, the system calls are not.

Historically, `fork` is the older system call. While it is very easy to define and use its semantics, it always suffered from its performance implications: The entire process environment needs to be (at least logically) copied, however, most of this work is for nothing, as one of the resulting processes is usually completely overwritten by an `exec` call. Also, the `fork` semantics do not allow for thread creation. Due to these shortcomings, the `clone` call was introduced, which allows fine grained control on what is copied, and what is shared between the two processes, allowing `pthreads` to be implemented in terms of `clone`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition of all the other answers, and to be picky, processes are created by [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) (or the obsolete [vfork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html)...) and [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) syscalls (and no, the [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) syscall don't create a process, but overwrite its address space and state by starting a new program in the same process), but some processes are "magically" created by the kernel, notably:

- `/sbin/init` is started by the kernel at startup (if not found, some other programs are tried, even `/bin/sh` ....); this is the process of pid 1 at is is started quite early...
- Some kernel processes (or kernel threads) are started by the kernel, like [kswapd](http://www.science.unitn.it/~fiorella/guidelinux/tlk/node39.html), `kworker` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846747/origin-of-a-kworker-thread) question), etc... I have more than 50 kernel processes or tasks
- The Linux kernel is also sometimes starting user processes from kernel land, notably [hotplug(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hotplug), [modprobe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modprobe),  etc... See also [udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) etc...
- Almost all processes are started by `fork` (or `clone` ...) and are descendants of `/sbin/init` (or the process of pid 1). (But `modprobe` or `hotplug` could be started by the kernel, and they usually `fork` other processes).

Process creation (thru `fork` etc....) is quite efficient. A shell is forking almost every command (except the builtin ones, like `cd` or `ulimit`...); `clone` is necessary for multi-threading (but can be used as a replacement of `fork`...)

Notice that [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html), [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) are *library functions* (not [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), which are listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) ...) calling both `fork` and `execve` (on `/bin/sh` ...) and that [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) is a library function calling `fork` (twice) etc...

Use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) (to find out which syscalls a program is executing) and read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

<sup>These days, recent Libc are using `clone` more than `fork` (and some are not calling the `fork` syscall any more but only `clone`); you can have several libc, eg [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org/) in addition (or in replacement) of [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)</sup>