# verifying where 'kworker/n:n' (in ps -aux) is invoked from

Tags: linux-kernel

In the result of 'ps -aux', I couldn't find how to verify that 'kworker/...' are created from and what module/functions are related to it.

Please let me know how I find out kworkers are from with pid or else.

I've try to check files in /proc, nothing is shown about this.

```
$ ps -aux | grep kworker
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug12   0:00 [kworker/1:0]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Aug12   0:00 [kworker/1:0H]
root        85  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Aug12   0:09 [kworker/0:1H]
root      3562  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Aug12   0:00 [kworker/0:2H]
root      5578  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:13   0:01 [kworker/0:0]
root      5579  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:13   0:00 [kworker/u4:1]
root      8789  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:19   0:10 [kworker/0:2]
root     30236  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    08:39   0:01 [kworker/u4:0]
```

Comment: You aware that kworker is just a kernel thread which is created entirely inside the kernel code, don't you? You may check this question on Ask Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/33640/kworker-what-is-it-and-why-is-it-hogging-so-much-cpu.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution for these kinds of problems that I'm familiar with is to use the **perf tool** (It's not always enabled by default and you may need to [install perf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50145/how-to-install-perf-monitoring-tool) on your device).

**Step 1:** Set perf to record workqueue events:

```
perf record -e 'workqueue:*' -ag -T
```

**Step 2:** Run it as long as you think you need to catch the event (10 seconds should be ok if this event is frequent enough, but you can let it run longer, depending on the available free space you have left on your device) and then stop it with `Ctrl + C`.

**Step 3:** Print the captured events (on Linux versions < 4.1 I think it should be -f and not -F):

```
perf script -F comm,pid,tid,time,event,trace
```

This will display something like this:

```
      task-name    pid/tid     timestamp    event 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    turtle        9201/9201   1473.339166:  workqueue:workqueue_queue_work:    work struct=0xef20d4c4 function=pm_runtime_work workqueue=0xef1cb600 req_cpu=8 cpu=1
    turtle        9201/9201   1473.339176:  workqueue:workqueue_activate_work: work struct 0xef20d4c4
    kworker/0:3  24223/24223  1473.339221:  workqueue:workqueue_execute_start: work struct 0xef20d4c4: function pm_runtime_work
    kworker/0:3  24223/24223  1473.339248:  workqueue:workqueue_execute_end:   work struct 0xef20d4c4
```

**Step 4:** Analyzing the table above:

In the first row, a task named `turtle (pid 9201)` is pushing the work `pm_runtime_work` to the workqueue. 
In the third row, we can see that the `kworker/0:3 (pid 24223)` is executing that work.

**Summary:** Now back to your questions, we see that `kworker/0:3` has been requested by `turtle` task to run the `pm_runtime_work` function.
Now, if you want to dig further, you'll have step into the code and see what the `pm_runtime_work` function does. Good luck !!!